# Get Keyvalue from URL (Inside View)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, razor

How can I get the last part of this url as string inside my .cshtml view?

```
http://localhost:10000/BusinessObject/Browse?Name=Game
```

The value I need is the Name -> so here it would be "**Game**".

Keys:

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}"
```

To get Controllers or Actions and so on I use this:

```
Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

But can anybody tell me how I would do something similiar to get the Namevalue - "Game"?

Comment: Have you tried `Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["name"]`?

Comment: sure, it returns `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your method in C# looks something like this:

```
    public ActionResult Browse(string Name)
    {
       //Do whatever
       return View()
    }
```

If this is the case then you could drop the Name into the ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Browse(string Name)
        {
           //Do whatever
           ViewBag.Name = Name;
           return View()
        }
```

Then on the webpage:

```
<p>@ViewBag.Name<p/>
```